# gem install rails fails to be executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rubymine

This command doesn't work and brings the following error:

[image]

And this is the screenshot of the file that in which I should have seen the error:

[image]

Comment: Have you installed the devkit?

Comment: It's best not to post your error as screenshot, just paste it into the question if you are able.

Comment: Have you installed Ruby yet? You must have Ruby installed on your computer before you can run the Rails framework.

Comment: Yes I've insstalled both ruby and msys32. I can run ruby programs but I can't install rails.